# How to handle Google Authentication with Strapi and React Native

Tags: react-native, google-oauth, strapi

I'm trying to implement Google Authentication in my React Native app and want to store all the data in Strapi. Strapi does provide Google Authentication support but I think that will work with SPAs. Please help me how to get started with it in React Native.

Answer (score 0):

I found a straight cut approach with firebase

1. setup/install firebase app, comes with [@react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/), just follow the installation steps
2. install [@react-native-google-signin/google-signin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin)
3. in firebase console enable google authentication and get Web client ID and  Web client secret
4. add these 2 in strapi google provider in Client ID and Client Secret respectively
5. Now, in react native app in login page

```html
import { GoogleSignin } from "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin";

GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId: "<web client ID>",
  forceCodeForRefreshToken: true,
  accountName: "",
});

const googleLogin = async () => {
  await GoogleSignin.signOut();
  await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
  await GoogleSignin.signIn();
  const { accessToken } = await GoogleSignin.getTokens();
  const response = await Api.get(
    `${strapi_url}/api/auth/google/callback?access_token=${accessToken}`
  );
};

// response -> you will have the strapi signed-in user
```

And all set!